# the file wont be opened with Hyperlink field associated to it

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

I have a Table with a field of Hyperlink datatype, which is populated with file location Hyperlink.

Then I have a form and listbox in it, the list box is populated with the above Table field.

Though listbox populated correctly, none of the files open when I click on them, it has a value for example

> "OPEN FILE#C:\1.pdf#"

The file exists, but nothing happen when I click on the field in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because listbox value is just a string of characters. Access does not recognize this as an actionable hyperlink because it is not activated from hyperlink field in table or hyperlink formatted control. Also, if listbox is bound to field then clicking item will change value in record.

Only textbox and combobox controls can be formatted as an actionable hyperlink. Both have IsHyperlink and DisplayAsHyperlink properties.

Could have VBA code behind listbox that extracts the middle hyperlink part with HyperlinkPart() intrinsic function and uses it in FollowHyperlink() intrinsic function.

I don't use hyperlink type fields. I save hyperlink to a text field then use VBA FollowHyperlink function or construct actionable hyperlink with an expression in query (and bind field to formatted textbox) or calculate in textbox:
`"#" & [Link] & "#"`